# CGContextClearRect ignores alpha value set in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm using CGContextClearRect method in MyView's drawRect to clear MyView to background color. However, I must explicitly set the background color alpha value of MyView in code. If I set the alpha value in storyboard, the CGContextClearRect makes MyView black. So why the alpha value set in storyboard doesn't do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawRect method allows you to reset the view's layer content when flagged for a refresh. There's is no need to call CGContextClearRect as clearing the layer is automatically managed by the system before it calls the drawRect method, effectively providing you with a blank canvas for the view's layer.